# UITextField overflow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield, quartz-core

I made a simple subclass for `UITextField` and it works as intended. The only problem I'm encountering is when the text value gets too large, it overflows into the clear button.

[image]

I can't seem to find out how to only alter the right side of the text to have some padding to not intersect with the clear button.

```
#import "TextField.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@implementation TextField

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.layer.borderColor = [[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor];
    [self.layer setBorderWidth:0.6];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectInset(bounds, 12, 0);
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
}

@end
```

I've managed to move BOTH sides of the text so it doesn't overflow into the button, but then the left side looks strange because it has extra spacing. How can I only add padding to the right side of the text or the left side of the clear button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just shift your rect over a bit.

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, bounds.origin.y, bounds.size.width - 10, bounds.size.height);
}
```

By extension your editing rect should update too since you're basing it off the textRect.